# How to avoid error when multiplying an array with one element in PDL?

Tags: arrays, perl, pdl

I've tried using PDL to multiply arrays in a faster way, but get an error with one-element piddles. The example code is

```
use PDL::Core;
use PDL::Primitive;

my $m = [ [ 2 ] ];
pdl($m) x pdl($m);
```

The error is:

```
Undefined subroutine &PDL::mult called at /home/user/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi/PDL/Primitive.pm line 263.
```

`Primitive.pm` source code is:

```
sub PDL::matmult {
    my ($a,$b,$c) = @_;

    $b = pdl($b) unless eval { $b->isa('PDL') };
    $c = PDL->null unless eval { $c->isa('PDL') };

    while($a->getndims < 2) {$a = $a->dummy(-1)}
    while($b->getndims < 2) {$b = $b->dummy(-1)}

    return ($c .= $a * $b) if( ($a->dim(0)==1 && $a->dim(1)==1) ||
                               ($b->dim(0)==1 && $b->dim(1)==1) );
    if($b->dim(1) != $a->dim(0)) {
        barf(sprintf("Dim mismatch in matmult of [%dx%d] x [%dx%d]: %d != %d",$a->dim(0),$a->dim(1),$b->dim(0),$b->dim(1),$a->dim(0),$b->dim(1)));
    }
    PDL::_matmult_int($a,$b,$c);
    $c;
}


*matmult = \&PDL::matmult;
```

It seems that multiplication is not defined when there is a single element. Is this a bug? Way it is the adequate way to solve it?

Comment: (FYI, I googled "Undefined subroutine &PDL::mult" and the question I linked in my previous comment was the first result)